# IE 8: move caret to the end of a text input field AND make the end visible

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to set the position of cursor/caret in a text box such that it is at the end of input control's text content.  There are plenty examples of doing this.  The tricky part is if the text extends beyond the width of the textbox, I'd like the text to 'scroll' into view so the end of the text and the caret are visible. This is exactly what is being asked in this question:

[move caret to the end of a text input field AND make the end visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692009/move-caret-to-the-end-of-a-text-input-field-and-make-the-end-visible)

There's a solution listed there that does work with Chrome and possibly later versions of IE (9 or later), but with IE 8 the solution doesn't work; there's no document.createEvent.  I tried to modify the code so that I use createEventObject & fireEvent:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {              
            e = document.createEventObject("KeyboardEvent");
                        e.keyCode = 35;
                        //textfield.fireEvent('onkeypress', e);
                        textBox.fireEvent('onkeydown', e);
                        textBox.fireEvent('onkeyup', e);

                        textBox.blur();
                        textBox.focus();
                }, 2000);
```

but this doesn't give the desired effect of horizontally scrolling the end of the text into view.  Is there any way to do this with IE 8?

Thanks!

Notre

EDIT: In the end, I used this function which seems to work on all major browsers based on my testing.

```
scrollCaretIntoView: function(textField) {

    if (textfield.selectionStart || textfield.selectionStart === 0) {
        //For all browsers, except IE 8 and earlier
        textfield.selectionStart = textfield.value.length;
        textfield.selectionEnd = textfield.value.length;
        textfield.blur(); // Webkit wake-up hack
        textfield.focus();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        //IE8 and earlier specific code
        textfield.focus();
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.moveEnd('character', 0); //move 0 characters from current position
        range.select();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I've found solution for IE8 (I tested it in IE8 ONLY). See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZxzH/)

Here is a JS code:

```
var rng = text.createTextRange();
rng.moveEnd( 'textedit' );
rng.moveStart( 'textedit' );
rng.select();
rng.scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: I think this will likely work.  I found another solution, which I ultimately used.  See comments above.